# Looping through a directory of files in Python

Tags: python, loops, elementtree, os.walk

I'm 99% of the way through my first python script, but I'm getting tripped up on the equivalent of a for-each loop through files in a directory. My script is working for single files, I'm just not sure how to apply it to multiple files, one at a time.

I have a path `path = ~/documents` and an XML file with filenames I would like to exclude:

```
 <root><synced name="Already Synced"><sfile name="Filename">base</sfile><sfile name="Filename">File1.blah</sfile><sfile name="Filename">File2.blah</sfile><sfile name="Filename">File3.blah</sfile></synced></root>
```

how would I run my script on, say, all files that end with `*.blah` and are NOT in the XML sfile?

I had this, but it was a no-go:

```
path = '~/documents'
tree = ET.parse("sync_list.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
for elem in root.findall('sfile'):
    synced = elem.text
do_library = os.listdir(path)
if glob.fnmatch.fnmatch(file,"*.blah") and not synced:
  for entry in do_library:
    file = os.path.join(path, entry)
    result = plistlib.readPlist('file')
```

Thank you so much for any help you can offer.

Comment: What is it doing and what do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import fnmatch
import os

path = os.path.expanduser('~/documents')
tree = ET.parse("sync_list.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
synced = [elt.text for elt in root.findall('synced/sfile')]
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, '*.blah') and filename not in synced:
        filename = os.path.join(path, filename)
```

Edit: Added os.path.expanduser, as suggested by @mata.

Comment: This is very close to working, but it doesn't seem to exclude the filenames listed in sync_list.xml. It did loop properly through the files, and run all of my logic.

Comment: `synced` was empty because `root.findall('sfile')` should have been `root.findall('synced/sfile')`. Perhaps try it now.

Answer (score 1):

```
path = '~/documents'
```

this doesn't give you the `documents` folder in your home-directory. `~` doesn't really stand for the home directory, what lets's you use it as if it were usually is the shell doing tilde expansion. Without that, `~` can be the name of any file or directory, and python treats it as such. To get it correctly, use:

```
path = os.path.expanduser('~/documents')
```